# Insert text including capture group from search using global command

Tags: global-command

I would like to search for a pattern in a range of lines and append additional text on another line that would include part of the search pattern. Something like this:

```
[range]g/\(foo \)\(\w\{-}\)/normal! 2jibar \2
```

but the callback to the capture group does not seem to work. It finds the pattern, moves two lines down, and inserts "bar \2" literally instead of "bar " + the result of the second capture group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:global` command does not make its capture groups available to the trailing command.  The simplest alternative is to use `\zs` and `\ze` to target the specific match and grab the pattern using the normal command;

```
g/foo \zs\w\{-}\ze/normal! ygn2jp
g/foo \zs\w\{-}\ze/normal! ygn2jibar ^R"
```

where ^R is a literal ctrl-r, which you type ctrl-v ctrl-r to enter.  This uses `ygn` to yank the next match, which is set appropriately due to the pattern in `:global`.

You can also write your own commands to be used in the trailing command slot.  For instance,

```
function! CaptureNormal(qargs, bang)
    let l:list = matchlist(getline('.'), (&magic?'\m':'\M').@/)
    let l:args = substitute(a:qargs, '\\\(\d\)', '\=l:list[submatch(1)]', 'g')
    execute 'normal'.a:bang l:args
endfunction

command! -bang -nargs=* CapNorm call CaptureNormal(<q-args>, '<bang>')
```

All this does is 1) match the line using the previous pattern to grab the capture groups, 2) adjust the given string to replace `\2` with the groups text, then 3) run the  pre-processed normal command.

```
[range]g/\(foo \)\(\w\{-}\)/CapNorm! 2jibar \2
```

Comment: The first option nailed it. Thanks. I don't really follow what's going in the `function!` example, though.